# SQL Server User-Defined Table Type / Crystal Reports Error

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I was forwarded a Crystal Reports error message that said:

> Failed to retrieve data from the database. ... Description: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xxxx_IDList', database 'DBName', schema 'dbo'.

There is an '*object?*' named 'xxxx.IDList' under User-Defined Table Types - in the database.

I have never created or used a User-defined Table Type so I am just trying to figure out how to approach this error and how I might proceed with troubleshooting it.

I am hoping this is not an uncommon error.

Can anyone suggest an approach to solving this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand that my post is lacking in specifics but I don't know how to provide any more information than I have  - given my limited knowledge of Crystal Reports.

Comment: seems like i see that when i cant execute a stored procedure.. try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/grant-permissions-on-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I agree with @TabAlleman, you should be able to grant execute permission to either your login or database role, whichever you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks, @Ryan Wilson! When I try 'Grant EXECUTE On dbo.xxxx_IDList to PUBLIC' - I get  this Message: "Cannot find the object 'xxxx_IDList', because it does not exist or you do not have permission." Since I know it exists, is there a way to include my admin credentials when I run that so it will be accepted?

Comment: Seems you have been given suggestions that don't appear to have any bearing on your problem. But it is pointless to try to "correct" something until you can reproduce the problem. So can you? It seems not but you are not clear about that. When you can reproduce it, then you need to find the query and sequence of events that leads to this error. Until you do that, this is one giant (and inefficient) guessing game.

Comment: Hi @SMor! I'm sorry my original question was unclear. I'll try & clarify. Several of us can reproduce the error at will. One person [who has Domain Admin rights] never has the issue when he runs under his domain admin credentials. However, if he runs the report under a different user id, he gets the error too. As we can't have everyone using the domain admin credentials, can you suggest another approach?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server, any table that is not a system table is a user-defined table.  So, anything in a typical non-system database that holds business data.  The error message tells me that you have a database (dbname) on the server you are connecting to.  In that database there is at least one schema (dbo, which is the default) and that the table xxxx_IDList lives in that schema.

Your app is trying to execute this table as if it was a function or stored procedure and you do not have permission to do that.

Do you have the source for the app that we can look at?

Comment: Thanks for the response! When you say 'the app', do you mean the source for the Crystal Report where this is happening? How would I retrieve the source?

Comment: I may not have been totally clear about the nature of the 'object' 'xxxx_IDList'. In my Object Explorer in SSMS, I find this object under Programmability | Types | User-defined Table Types. This is not under 'Tables'. If I use this SQL: "Select * from sys.objects Where name like '%xxxx_IDList%' no rows are returned.

Comment: OK a table type. you may not have permissions to use it.  Hence the cryptic error message.  try sys.types

Comment: Thanks! I see it when I run 'Select * from sys.types Where Name like '%xxxx_IDList%'. How do we restore permissions to the User who is getting that error? Is it as simple as running a 'Grant EXECUTE on xxxx.IDList' ...? He was able to run this Crystal Report in the past.

Comment: Should be that simple.  give it a whirl.  Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-type-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I tried running a 'Grant EXECUTE on xxxx.IDList to UserName' but was told the object doesn't exist or I don't have permission.

Comment: You confirmed the object exists, so that implies you don't have permission.  What is your role in the database?